# Show that a compact metric space $X$ is locally compact

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Assume that $X$ is a compact metric space, that is by definition, every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence.

Locally compact means that every point in $X$ has a compact neighbourhood. That is, for every point in $x \in X$ we can find an open ball for which every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

So now what I need to do is take an arbitrary sequence $(x_{n})$ in a ball around $x_0 \in X$ and show that it has a convergent subsequence. How do I do that?

Comment: The ball is inside the metric space, so the sequence has a convergent subsequence. It follows trivially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you just want some compact neighbourhood of $x \in X$ you can just take the whole space $X$ itself. Notice that since compact metric spaces are bounded this is also an open ball centered at $x$.

Often this is the only choice for a compact neighbourhood of $x$ which is also an open ball: As every compact subset of a metric space is closed (because metric spaces are Hausdorff) every such ball must be clopen. So if $X$ is connected, for example $X = [0,1]$, we have no other choice.

---

I think it is important to point out that your definition of a locally compactness *does not* require the compact neighbourhood of $x$ to be an open ball, which you (incorrectly) seem to assume.

Not only makes this assumption the given problem more difficult, but it can fail you for non-compact spaces: Take for example the real line $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard euclidian metric. This is a locally compact metric space (for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $[x-1,x+1]$ is a compact neighbourhood of $x$), but as $\mathbb{R}$ is connected we find by the above argumentation that a compact, open ball centered at $x \in \mathbb{R}$ would need to be the whole space, which is absurd.

---

I would also like to point out that a compact metric space $X$ does already satisfy the alternative and stronger definition of a locally compact space, namely that every $x \in X$ has a neighbourhood basis of compact neighbourhoods, i.e. that every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ contains a compact neighbourhood. To see this notice that there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ with $B_{2\varepsilon}(x) \subseteq U$, which is why $\overline{B_{\varepsilon}(x)} \subseteq U$. This is a neighbourhood of $x$, as it contains $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$, and as a closed subset of the compact space $X$ it is compact itself.

Comment: Thank you, this is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the open ball be any open ball, and since $X$ is compact metric, every sequence in that open ball has a convergent subsequence. This is pretty much trivial.

Comment: It's not quite that trivial.  Yes, every sequence in an open ball in $X$ has a convergent subsequence, but not necessarily convergent to a point **of the ball**.  So open balls in a compact metric space are not necessarily compact.  Closed balls are, though.  Or you could take the neighbourhood to be the whole space...

Comment: @RobertIsrael so you are saying, because I can choose any neighbourhood of $x_0$, I may as well take the entire space $X$ to be the neighbourhood, which is of course compact by assumption?

Comment: @RobertIsrael The definition of local compactness for OP does not require this.

Comment: @vanderlylic Yes, and that is why this is pretty much trivial.

Comment: @HenryW.  The definition of local compactness as the OP stated it was "every point has a compact neighborhood."  OP then interpreted this (incorrectly) as "an open ball for which every sequence has a convergent subsequence."